# How to use xpath to get href value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="AdvancedSearchResultsContainter">
        <table id="SearchResults" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="header">School name</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="header">School type</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="header">Sector</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr class="odd">

                        <td><a href="/Home/Index/82604">ABC Public School</a></td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Primary</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Government</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="even">

                        <td><a href="/Home/Index/82721">XYZ High School</a></td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Secondary</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Government</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">

                        <td><a href="/Home/Index/82648">PQR Park Public School</a></td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Primary</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Government</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="even">

                        <td><a href="/Home/Index/82635">JKL Public School</a></td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Primary</td>
                        <td class="nowrap">Government</td>
                    </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I am using selenum and xpath .
I want to get the numeric value of href .Out of this href 
 i want to get 82648. like to put it in loop and get all numeric in href.

can some one please help.

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: WebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.getDriver("Chrome");

Comment: List<WebElement> elementsHref = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='SearchResults']/a/@href"));    
                System.out.println("Testehref number of elements: " + elementsHref.size());

                for(WebElement elehref : elementsHref){
                    //ele.sendKeys("hexbyes");
                    System.out.println("Text href======>"+elehref.getText());
                    
                    System.out.println("TagName href===>"+elehref.getTagName());
                }I dont think i am using any selenum binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following css selector to get the `<a>` element:

```
By.cssSelector("#SearchResults tr a");
```

Then get all the link elements by using `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#SearchResults tr a"))` and the use `getAttribute("href")` to get the urls

Something like:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#SearchResults tr a"));
```

Get the urls and then do whatever you want. The java.lang.String class provides a lot of methods to work on string. By the help of these methods, we can perform operations on string such as trimming, concatenating, converting, comparing, replacing strings etc. As an example:

```
for(WebElement e : elements) {
        String url = e.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(url.substring(url.length()-5));
    }
```

There are  other methods to get the substring as well.
Also you can write a method which will return a `String` and then you can assert if you intend to do so.

Comment: great !!! worked like a charm.i have one more question.Can i ask here or start a new question.

Comment: May be start a new one as others can also help.

Comment: started a new one "how to use xpath to get values from td and th"